# Breadcrumb problem in Expression Engine

Tags: php, html, expressionengine, breadcrumbs

I am having a small issue in expression engine, I have created a breadcrumb snippet. I have created it using {if segment_} coding.

So I created an if rule for each of the pages (it's not a huge site) however I am having a problem with one of the breadcrumb trials. I have numerous categories with a product view page, on this product view page I can't seem to place the category in the breadcrumb. Placing the category in the actual category page is no problem, i've used:

```
{if segment_4 == "toys"}<li><a href="index.php/product/category/toys">Toys</a></li>{/if}
```

However on the permalink page I can't do this as there are no toys in the url.

I know this is an easy fix, i'm just not very familiar with categories on expression engine.

Comment: Are you only assigning one category per product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky question, because an entry (product) can be assigned to *more than one category*.

For the sake of an example, if you are **only assigning *one category per product***, you can use the following code for a basic breadcrumbs trail in your permalink template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="product" limit="1"}
    <ul class="breadcrumbs">
        <li><a href="{path='site_index'}">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{path='product/index'}">{channel}</a></li>
            {categories limit="1" channel="product"}
                <li>
                    <a href="{path='product/index'}">{category_name}</a>
                </li>
            {/categories}
        <li>{title}</li>
    </ul>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Which would output something along the lines of:

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <li><a href="http://localhost/index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/index.php/product">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/index.php/product/category/toys">Toys</a></li>
    <li>Buzz Lightyear Action Figure</li>
</ul>
```

**Depending upon how you've setup the taxonomy of your site (*single category for products vs. multiple categories*) will determine if you can safely use categories in your breadcrumbs.**

Since you didn't post more of your code, you may choose to implement things differently, especially if you're using an [embeddd template](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/embedding_templates.html) for your breadcrumbs. However, you can extract out the necessary bits from this example to suit your environment.

In addition, you can use ExpressionEngine's [URL Segment Variables](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/url_segments.html), [Category URL Indicator](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide//cp/admin/content_admin/global_channel_preferences.html) and [Conditional Global Variables](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html) to add even more flexibility.

---

I may also mention that if you're looking for a rapid and highly customizable solution to adding breadcrumbs to your site, you might want to consider the commercial add-on [Crumbly](http://experienceinternet.co.uk/software/crumbly/) by Stephen Lewis of Experience Internet.